# How to Enable "Copy To SIM" feature in Nokia C12 Smartphone?

Tags: android, nokia

Good evening folks!

How do we enable the feature "Copy from SIM to Mobile Phone" feature in the Nokia C12 Smartphone? I ended up coming here because I have no idea how to post questions on the Official Nokia forum like this one

"https://community.phones.nokia.com/"

I just ended up running on circles on that site so I came here for guidance.

Currently, my phone displays contacts from my SIM Card like this one..

[list Of Contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWcZO.jpg)

But I couldn't find the option "Copy from SIM to Mobile Phone" feature in the Nokia C12 Smartphone like this one:

[No Copy from SIM to Mobile Phone option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GYP5.jpg)

I would like to copy the cellphone numbers from my SIM card to my Nokia C12 Smartphone.

How do we enable the  "Copy from SIM to Mobile Phone" feature in the Nokia C12 Smartphone?

I tried finding the "Copy from SIM to Mobile Phone" feature in the Nokia C12 Smartphone but I couldn't find such option.

Thank you all!

Comment: well, Nokia forum is proper place for asking such question, in here we are talking about programming and your problem isn't related at all...